# Get different valid frame number from the same video on different cpu using opencv-python?

Tags: python, video, opencv

I am using opencv-python==4.2.0.32 to extract frames from videos following the code.

```
def read_1(self, video_path, delta=0.5):
        video  = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        fps    = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        frames = math.ceil(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        step = int(fps * delta)
        print(f'fps: {fps} step: {step} frames: {frames}')
    
        for i in range(frames):
            flag, img = video.read()
            if flag:
                yield img
```

However, for some videos, the valid frame number is totally different on different CPU machines. Is it caused by hardware or the codecs?

Does anybody meet this problem?